# How to use pam_echo.so in /etc/pam.d/sudo

Tags: linux, pam, echo

I want to be able to echo a simple message in between password authentication and yubikey challenge response authentication when using sudo.

I've tried multiple ways to do it, such as pam_echo.so and pam_script.so but nothing seems to work. To my knowledge that is because sudo calls pam_authenticate with the pam_silent flag.

Here are some examples of what I tried:

```
auth    required    pam_echo.so      file=/etc/security/sudo-msg.conf
auth    required    pam-script.so    onsessionopen=/etc/security/sudo-msg.sh
```

No errors occured in my testing to my knowledge.

I've found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/888188/why-cant-i-use-pam-echo-so-in-the-sudo-pam-stack) previous thread, but it doesn't answer my question, just says that "I can't do it". But there clearly is a way because the pam_yubico module has a debug parameter that prints stuff.

How can I echo my message aka how do I display stuff ignoring the PAM_SILENT flag?

Comment: Can you paste examples what you tried and where with error if any occurred?

Comment: Ok done @asktyagi